# Sending data to a website from a WCF service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, wcf, error-handling

I have the following setup

- A jQuery website (not exactly single page, but not far from it), that uses a
- A ASP.NET MVC website as a backend, which connects (via net.tcp or net.pipe) to
- A self-hosted WCF service that manages and connects to
- A plethora of high-latency external services.

So when a client pushes a button, a request is sent to the MVC, which routes it to the WCF, which aggregates it from the external services, and everything is fine and dandy.

The issue I can't seem to wrap my head around is communication in the other way, i.e. when one of the external services goes offline, what is the easiest and most elegant way to inform the client (the browser)?

This means that the service should somehow inform the mvc site that should somehow inform the client that an external service is offline.

Additionally: The external service will have high availability, so the "goes offline" scenario will be seldom used, and accordingly I'm looking for a solution that does not do extensive polling of the server.

Comment: How do you define "offline"? Temporarily unreachable? Shut down for maintenance by an administrator at the external service? Is this strictly for dealing with "planned" outages or are you looking to gracefully handle any inability to contact the remote services?

Comment: @RickLiddle "goes dark" might be a better word here. Basically, when the external service (which is outside my command) is not responding as it should.

Comment: I highly recommend the SignalR suggestion provided by JcFx [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12863194/35241).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working on a similar architecture and am planning to use [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) to push updates from WCF, (sometimes directly, sometimes via Azure Service Bus), to a single-page jQuery-driven app. I haven't implemented this yet, though, so there may be some issues I haven't considered.

From their docs:

> Pushing data from the server to the client (not just browser clients)
>   has always been a tough problem. SignalR makes it dead easy and
>   handles all the heavy lifting for you.

Scott Hansleman has a good blog on the topic here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Comment: Upvoted -- excellent solution that provides a viable answer to the problem at hand AND includes great resources. This is, IMO, the model of what an answer on StackOverflow should be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fault exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx) to return exception data to the client.

I prefer to have an `IsSuccessful` flag on my returned contracts and only throw fault exceptions when there's a critical error.

Here's a very basic example of a response contract with an `IsSuccessful` flag.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsSuccessful { get { return Message == null || !Messages.Any(); } set { } }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

`Messages` can be complex types if you need to provide more detailed information. `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes can be `MessageContract` and `MessageBodyMember` if that suits your architecture better.

Comment: isn't simple Json a lot easier?

Comment: I might not have stated the question clear, sorry. There is no request from the client, the server should initiate the communication.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you will need to implement some type in polling service to ping these external services for their availability.

Comment: That is already implemented on the WCF service level, and upon request available to the client. The problem is that now I need to send it to the client in an event-driven way.

Comment: What is the client?  Is this web-based?

Comment: Yes, I've described so in question.

Answer (score 0):

The typical scenario with WCF and a browser is a request/response pattern. The browser makes a request and the service responds.

You can have the browser periodically poll the service looking for status.

Comment: The external service will have high availability, so the "goes offline" scenario will be seldom used, and accordingly I'm looking for a solution that does not do extensive polling of the server.

Comment: In that case, simply return a fault when the external service is offline and the browser makes a request that requires it.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Discovery Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.aspx) there is functionality that allows a WCF service to send out discovery messages. If you have a planned outage the [AnnouncementClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.announcementclient.aspx) has methods for the service to publish messages about going offline/online.

To set a custom message for your users you need to listen for these Announcement messages. The class that implements this is [AnnouncementService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.announcementservice.aspx). It has events for handling [Offline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.announcementservice.offlineannouncementreceived.aspx) and [Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.announcementservice.onlineannouncementreceived.aspx) messages.